# How to get label text from web table

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm facing the problem with finding label text from table 
I'm new to Selenium, help me understand what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

```java
WebElement services = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@id='mr_2']/label"));
String strServices = services.getText();
System.out.println(strServices);
```

```
<tr class="alt" id="mr_2">
<td class="first_col">Menu Selection</td>
<td><label style="display: none" for="element_2_1">Poor</label>
<input id="element_2_1" name="element_2" type="radio" value="1"></td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error message or an empty string?

Comment: Hello, I'm getting an empty String only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the below line

```
String strServices = services.getText();
```

to

```
String strServices = services.getAttribute("textContent");
```